# How do you delete a message field from a proto in C++?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, proto

If you have a proto like:

```proto
message B {
  bool field_bool = 1;
}

message A {
  B field_b = 1;
}
```

How can you completely delete the `field_b` message from an instance of `A`?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `clear_` method:

```cpp
A message_a;
message_a.mutable_b()->set_field_bool(true);

// Now delete B:
message_a.clear_field_b();
```